# What is the meaning of "FQ2"?

Tags: accounting, terminology

I see the words FQ2 used in news reports sometimes, but I don't know what it means. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Can you provide any context to this? A link to an example of its use?

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna guess [Fiscal Quarter 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_Year).

Comment: This. To expand, the fiscal year of a company does not always correspond to the calendar year; i.e. the last day of FQ2 is not always June 30 for all companies. There are a number of reasons to offset the fiscal year. Use of FQ vs simply Q is sometimes ambiguous, but typically when FQ is used it is in the context of a single company and signifies the use of the company's fiscal calendar; usually when talking about an entire industry or the market as a whole, quarters i.e. Q2 are calendar quarters.